# Smooth floor function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions, approximation-theory

I want a monotonic function on the positive real numbers that behaves like floor but in smooth way, like smoothstep but for all integers.
It should follow this simple rule.

> slope is zero at integers and slope is maximum at median of two adjacent integers or in other words: slope is at $0$ when fract$(x) = 0$ and slope is at maximum when fract$(x)=0.5$

So far i was able to approximate this function my self with help of trigonometric functions. 
$$
f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + \max\left(\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}{2}(1-\cos(\pi x)), \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor x+1\rfloor}}{2}(1-\cos(\pi x + \pi))\right)
$$
can this be achieved in a simpler/shorter way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What do yo think of :
$$y(x)=x-\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi}$$

[image]

Comment: brilliant function. smooth and clean! thanks

Comment: A monotonic function is a function which is either entirely nonincreasing or nondecreasing. A function is monotonic if its first derivative (which need not be continuous) does not change sign. The proposed function is entirely  nondecreasing. Its first derivative $y'(x)=1-\cos(2\pi x)\geq 0$ doesn't change sign. So, I think it is monotonic.

Comment: you are right. i made a mistake in putting the formula correctly. my apologize.

Comment: No need to apologize for that. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

The floor function is equivalent to `x-sawtooth(x)`, where sawtooth is the sawtooth wave function. By taking a trigonometric approximation of the sawtooth wave from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38293/make-a-differentiable-smooth-sawtooth-waveform we can derive an approximation of floor:

```
δ = 0.01;
trg[x_] := 1 - 2 ArcCos[(1 - δ) Sin[2 π x]]/π;
sqr[x_] := 2 ArcTan[Sin[2 π x]/δ]/π;
swt[x_] := (1 + trg[(2 x - 1)/4] sqr[x/2])/2;
flr[x_] := x-swt[x]
```

where δ is a parameter that controls the approximation. Here is a picture of the resulting function: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH6zT.png